# LG G2 call log types are different from Android CallLog.Calls reference

Tags: android, calllog, lg

I am trying to write an app the analyses user's call logs and find out 'close' people from the recent call activities.  I am working with a G2, and I am facing an issue.

Reading from the CallLog.Calls Android Developers References, there are pre-defined values that should match the call activities.  But, the G2 is giving me very different values at the moment.

For example, OUTGOING ought to be of value 2, but the examining the call log, it seems to hold value 6502.  All calls have "650" in front of the desired values.  Also, SMS/MMS are showing up in CallLog.Calls with values that are 3 integers long and start with 8.

Is this the case only for LG G2, or other recently release smart phones?  How should I develop the app so it can be used on all phones?  If LG does it in its own way, other manufacturers may as well?  I cannot afford phones from all manufacturers to check their values.

Please advise me regarding the issue!  I am using the following piece of code to get the Type value.

```
int type = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
String callType = cursor.getString(type);
```